# MongoDB PHP get unique month names

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoid

I have a created-at field in my news collection that saves dates

```
"created-at": new Date(2010, 11, 5);
```

im using the date function in PHP to get month names

```
date('F', $obj['created-at']->sec);
```

What im trying to do is to make it only output unique month names, so instead of lets say:
november, november, december

i want it to output:
november, december

ive tried using distinct but it wont work in my case

```
$db->command(array("distinct" => "news", "key" => "created-at"));
```

is there anyway i can output unique month names from the created-at field? or will i have to add a month-name field and use distinct on that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not an optimal solution but this is what i did to get unique month names if anyones interested

I ended creating an array $stack
and pushing all month names to the stack using array_push
then i used array_unique to get all the unique values in the stack

Comment: If you want to make this a little bit more efficient, push the results as the keys of an array, rather than as the values, then use array_keys() to get the final set.  As in:  $months[$month] = true;  return array_keys($months);